# What does the phrase 「かかってこんかい」 mean?

Tags: colloquial-language, phrases, video-games

It is said by a boss before a battle begun in a video game.

Does the こんかい mean 'now' in this phrase?

Does it share the same meaning with 「かかってこい」(bring it on)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does the こんかい mean 'now' in this phrase?

No. There is no relation with 'こんかい'（'今回'）（'this time'）.

> Does it share the same meaning with 「かかってこい」(bring it on)?

Basically yes.

According to [this source](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84), `(ん)かい` supposed to be Osaka dialect. But now it is very popular expression for entire Japanese.

かかってこんかい can be divided into `かかって` `こ` **`ない`** `か` **`よ`**

> かかってこないか

This sounds too polite but it directly means like `why don't you bring it on?`. Depending on the context, it also sounds like `I thought you're going to bring it on, but you did not`.

> かかってこないか*よ*

By adding 'よ' at the end of this line it adds kind of exclamation, though this also sounds too polite and awkward.

> かかってこんかい

Changing the form from `ないかよ` to `んかい`, it sounds very natural, modern and young language and it makes this line energetic.
It also makes the line more provocative, especially considering the original meaning of 'かかってこい'. Just like `How dare you don't bring it on?`

By the way, we also often use this expression in Japanese comedy or such situation.
When person A('boke') pretending to do something, but he/she didn't do in the end. Person B('tsukkomi') typically says `やらんか〜〜い`.
In this case, `(ん)かい` emphasizes the surprise feeling that person A didn't do that, and it makes us laugh.